# Enabling DHCP on Linux Host for libvirt VMs

Tags: linux, dhcp, bridge, libvirt, dhcp-server

This is a follow up question from here: [How to disable default DHCP on virbr0 and obtain IP from DHCP on host](https://serverfault.com/questions/1003855/how-to-disable-default-dhcp-on-virbr0-and-obtain-ip-from-dhcp-on-host?noredirect=1#comment1305220_1003855)

I have a **Ubuntu server 18.04**, with Libvirt based Virtual Machines setup over **virbr0** bridge. By default libvirt's default DHCP server (**dnsmasq**) provides IP address assignments through the bridge.

I have replaced the default bridge with a new one "**br0**" which has one enslaved port on my server "**enp7s0**". The Virtual Machines are also connected to this bridge, and all 3 interfaces (1 on the server and other 2 on the virtual machines) are communicable using static IP addresses 192.169.x.x/16.

**I want to use DHCP on the server to assign IP addresses to the VMs over the new bridge br0.**

1. Taking example of libvirt, the default dhcp server ran by libvirt, on what interface does a VM send DHCP requests to receive IP assignments ? virbr0? in other words, on which interface is the libvirt's dhcp server listening on ?
2. If I want to deploy my own DHCP server on the Ubuntu server, which interface should the DHCP server listen on "**enp7s0**" or "**br0**" ?

Answer (score 0):

the ip address is on the bridge interface br0, I assume, so the dhcp service should listen on that interface.

To be sure, verify the output of bot ip addr and ip link from the hypervisor.